# create ansible dict from two list with a condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I have many strings like this stored in list one

```
set bgp x vlan y tags-vlan bgp z,
set bgp x1 vlan y1 tags-vlan bgp z1,
.
.
.
.
```

and a second list contain values like this:

```
f,
j,
h,
m
```

from the first list of strings, i want to trim it and create from it a dict that contain values in this form:

```
bgp: x
vlan:y
tags-vlan bgp:z
-----
(to be added) details: p
```

and then add to the dict a fourth key called "**details**" which it's value is equal to the third value "h" in the second list, but add this key to the dict only when each time j == z, meaning second element of second list must equal third key value in newly made dict z and both have numeric value then add h to dict with the key name details.

the result is a dictionary like this, with h value being added with condition whenver z == j

```
bgp: x
vlan:y
tags-vlan bgp:z
details: h
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question and format your code/output/examples correctly. Check the buttons on top of the editor and the help button for further information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the strings

```yaml
  s1: |-
    set bgp x vlan y tags-vlan bgp z,
    set bgp x1 vlan y1 tags-vlan bgp z1,
    set bgp x2 vlan y2 tags-vlan bgp j
  s2: |-
    f,
    j,
    h,
    m
```

---

1. Split the lines

```yaml
  l1: "{{ s1|split('\n')|join()|split(',') }}"
  l2: "{{ s2|split('\n')|join()|split(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  l1:
  - set bgp x vlan y tags-vlan bgp z
  - set bgp x1 vlan y1 tags-vlan bgp z1
  - set bgp x2 vlan y2 tags-vlan bgp j

  l2:
  - f
  - j
  - h
  - m
```

2. Using the condition

If

```
 'the second item of the second list' == 'the value of the third key'
```

add

```
 {'details':  'third item of the second list'}
```

Create the structure

```yaml
    s3: |
      {% for i in l1 %}
      {% set a=i.split(' ') %}
      - {{ a.1 }}: {{ a.2 }}
        {{ a.3 }}: {{ a.4 }}
        {{ a.5 }} {{ a.6 }}: {{ a.7 }}
      {% if a.7 == l2.1 %}
        details: {{ l2.2 }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  s3: |-
  - bgp: x
    tags-vlan bgp: z
    vlan: y
  - bgp: x1
    tags-vlan bgp: z1
    vlan: y1
  - bgp: x2
    details: h
    tags-vlan bgp: j
    vlan: y2
```

3. Convert the string to yaml

```yaml
  l3: "{{ s3|from_yaml }}"
```

gives the list of the dictionaries

```yaml
  l3:
  - bgp: x
    tags-vlan bgp: z
    vlan: y
  - bgp: x1
    tags-vlan bgp: z1
    vlan: y1
  - bgp: x2
    details: h
    tags-vlan bgp: j
    vlan: y2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    s1: |-
      set bgp x vlan y tags-vlan bgp z,
      set bgp x1 vlan y1 tags-vlan bgp z1,
      set bgp x2 vlan y2 tags-vlan bgp j
    s2: |-
      f,
      j,
      h,
      m

    l1: "{{ s1|split('\n')|join()|split(',') }}"
    l2: "{{ s2|split('\n')|join()|split(',') }}"
    s3: |
      {% for i in l1 %}
      {% set a=i.split(' ') %}
      - {{ a.1 }}: {{ a.2 }}
        {{ a.3 }}: {{ a.4 }}
        {{ a.5 }} {{ a.6 }}: {{ a.7 }}
      {% if a.7 == l2.1 %}
        details: {{ l2.2 }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    l3: "{{ s3|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: l1
    - debug:
        var: l2
    - debug:
        var: s3
    - debug:
        var: l3
```